# Jquery insert data to server loop data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code, I want to insert the data from loop but i got error Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation 
         window.items = '';

```
        _.forEach(cart.items, function(n, key) {
var settings = {

  "async": true,
 "crossDomain": true,
 "url": "myurl",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "x-csrf-token": user_token,
"cache-control": "no-cache"

   },
 "data": {
"order_id": order,
"type": "product",
"commerce_product": n.id,
"quantity": n.cant
 }
}

 $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
 console.log(response);
});
           total = total  + (n.cant * n.price)
           items += '<li>'
           items += '<img src="'+n.img+'" />'
           items += '<h3 class="name">'+n.name+'<br><span class="price">'+n.cant+' x  '+n.price+' </span>'
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var mapResult = $.map(cart.items, function(value) {
 }
```

than user value